# How to fix MIME type of "text/html"?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, module, node-modules

i wanted to make docx file through html and js, also i'm using Docx Library and Filesaver

but i got next error:

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I'm using next html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=chrome">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav></nav>
    <section>
        <button>
            <input type="file" id="input">
            <button style="display: block; margin-top: 5em;" id="generate">Create custom DOCX type from XL document</button>
        </button>
    </section>
    <footer></footer>
    <script type="module" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and js:

```js
import { Document, Packer } from "../node_modules/docx/build/index"
import { saveAs } from "../node_modules/file-saver/dist/FileSaver"

document.getElementById("generate").addEventListener(
    "click",
    function (event) {
        generateWordDocument(event)
    },
    false
)
function generateWordDocument(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    // Create a new instance of Document for the docx module
    let doc = new Document()
    // Call saveDocumentToFile with the document instance and a filename
    saveDocumentToFile(doc, "New Document.docx")
}
function saveDocumentToFile(doc, fileName) {
    // Create new instance of Packer for the docx module
    const packer = new Packer()
    // Create a mime type that will associate the new file with Microsoft Word
    const mimeType =
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
    // Create a Blob containing the Document instance and the mimeType
    packer.toBlob(doc).then(blob => {
        const docblob = blob.slice(0, blob.size, mimeType)
        // Save the file using saveAs from the file-saver package
        saveAs(docblob, fileName)
    })
}

const inputElement = document.getElementById("input");
inputElement.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);
let fileList = inputElement.files
function handleFiles() {
    fileList = this.files; /* now you can work with the file list */
    console.log(fileList[0].name)
}
```

i download docx and file-saver next way:

> npm install docx

> npm install file-saver

and http-server

I'm using http-server to test my code

> http-server -c-1

how to fix MIME type of text/html in this code?

I tried to change path to docx and file-saver
like
"../package.json/docx"
"docx"
"../node_modules/docx"
and etc but it didn't work
i also tried to use another server as http-server and live server in vscode but nothing is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with your DOCX stuff. It's complaining about the MIME type on the response for `js/script.js` it gets when requesting your module. Apparently, `http-server` is returning `text/html` as the content-type for that, which isn't allowed; it has to be a valid JavaScript MIME type (such as `text/javascript`, though `application/javascript` and a few others are okay).

[The `http-server` documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) says you can pass `--mimetypes` to specify a `.types` file containing the MIME types to use, telling it to use `text/javascript` as the MIME type (possibly with a `charset`), although it doesn't tell you what the format of that file should be (you can probably work it out from the source). Or you might consider another server that handles this automatically.

Comment: Ye, problem was in server, i just changed to parcel and everything is working now thx